# C# - Detect three game objects in the correct order

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, logic

I have switches in Unity 3 that I operate with my player. At the moment I set one variable each to TRUE.
Now I want a trapdoor to open after pressing the switch. But this should only happen if you press the switches in the right order. 
How do I solve this in C# code? 
Don't get into the logic.

Maybe somebody with a code example can help me how this could look like. It could be pseudo code as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have a collection that contains the IDs of the switches in the order you expect.
2. When they press their switches, add the ID of the switches to another collection.
3. When collection length == number of switches, compare the IDs in the collection to the IDs in the same position in the expected order.  If they match, then open the trapdoor.